# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException :Invalid uri

Tags: java, url

I am trying GET response for an uri but everytime i get is error message "Invalid uri"
Here is what i tried out(Code snippet) :

```
String sAttachURL = "https://rt4.de.company.com/gx/service/com.ibm.rqm.integration.service.IIntegrationService/resources/Electric_TM/executionworkitem?fields=feed/entry/content/executionworkitem/testplan[@href=\"rt4.de.company.com/gx/service/com.ibm.rqm.integration.service.IIntegrationService/resources/Electric_TM/testplan/urn:com.ibm.rqm:testplan:27\"]";
GetMethod method = new GetMethod(sAttachURL);
```

Here also if i hit the same url in RESTClient, response is coming properly also if try triggering something like this :

```
String sAttachURLService = "https://rt4.de.company.com/gx/service";
GetMethod method = new GetMethod(sAttachURLService);
```

Response is coming properly via my code but only for **sAttachURL** its throws error not sure why i also feel [ ] brackets here might possible be causing some issue while encoding not sure
Can anyone please help me out here

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to percent-encode your brackets ? %5B for [ and %5D for ], so in your case :

```
String sAttachURL = "https://rt4.de.company.com/gx/service/com.ibm.rqm.integration.service.IIntegrationService/resources/Electric_TM/executionworkitem?fields=feed/entry/content/executionworkitem/testplan%5B@href=\"rt4.de.company.com/gx/service/com.ibm.rqm.integration.service.IIntegrationService/resources/Electric_TM/testplan/urn:com.ibm.rqm:testplan:27\"%5D";
```

Comment: Thanks for addressing my query but i tried this as well but still the same issue :)